# Lib not uninstalling from site packages (Python)

Tags: python, site-packages

I accidentally installed a lib site package and I am unable to remove it. When I run my python script, it is unable to import a file as it is looking for my file in the wrong directory.

```
from lib import mailparser // This is the line of the code that is failing. I want it to look for a lib folder in my directory of my project, not in my system
```

It isn't a problem with my code as it was working before and I am not looking to change it.

When I run my script, I am receiving this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'mailparser' from 'lib' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lib/__init__.py)
```

Here it is looking for a lib folder in my system, not in my project directory. Subsequently, I try to uninstall the lib site package but I receive this:

```
WARNING: Skipping lib as it is not installed.
```

Why is `from lib import mailparser` looking for a folder on my system and not in my project directory as this was working before!

Comment: Usage
pip uninstall [options] <package> ...
pip uninstall [options] -r <requirements file> ...

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lib/
```

I wouldn't recommend this to anyone else as I don't know what future problems I will face because of it. However, it worked for me and my code is now looking in the correct directory.

I tried `pip uninstall lib` but it was not uninstalling this module so I had to do a force remove.

Answer (score 0):

Run this without your virtualenv:

```
pip uninstall -y <package_name>
```

to uninstall it from /user/local/lib

However, in order to use the package in your project directory, you must have a virtualenv set up.

```
cd <project_dir>
virtualenv -v venv
source venv/bin/activate  # don't forget this before running your code

pip install <package>
```

Then you should be able to run your code in project directory